# What is the equivalence of Git-blame in bazaar?

Tags: git, bazaar, blame

Is there an equivalence of `git blame` in bazaar?
If so, what's the command for doing that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's

```
bzr annotate
```

As it happens, `blame` is a built-in alias for `annotate`.

I'm a git user, not a bazaar user, but since `bzr` provides this alias for a common `git` command, it's likely that `bzr some-git-command` is a good way to find the `bzr` equivalent of a given `git` command.

(BTW, `bzr praise` is also an alias for `bzr annotate`.)